# Как сохранить критические данные (пароль) между запросами?

Tags: http

Я пишу сайт файлообменник.
Он содержит дерево для просмотра файлов в папке сервера. Пользователь нажимает на папку и на сервер передаётся `GET` запрос с параметром, который содержит путь к папке. Сервер возвращает `JSON` представление структуры файлов в этой папке и у пользователя "разворачивается" ветка дерева этой папки. Если выбранный пользователем файл является архивом, то сервер возвращает `JSON` представление структуры папок в архиве. Если архив зашифрован паролем, сервер возвращает ошибку и просит пользователя ввести пароль, чтобы показать ему содержимое архива.

---

***Вопрос в следующем:***

1. Как безопасно передать пароль с помощью `GET` запроса? (я знаю, что это глупая идея, но я надеюсь, что вы предложите другой способ. Не `PUT` же мне использовать)
2. Как сохранить пароль от предыдущего запроса, если архивы вложены и пользователю нужно ввести оба пароля?

```
# Исходное дерево:

+--- Root
|    +--- Folder 1
|    \--- File 1

# Пользователь нажал на "Folder 1"

+--- Root
|    +--- Folder 1
|    |    +--- Folder 2
|    |    |--- Archive 1
|    |    \--- Folder 3
|    \--- File 1


# Пользователь нажал на "Archive 1"
# Сервер попытался отобразить файлы "Archive 1"
# и оказалось, что он требует пароль
# Сервер возвращает "Forbidden" и перед
# пользователем появляется модальное окно с
# предложением ввести пароль. Пользователь
# вводит пароль и он отправляется (КАК?)
# вместе с запросом "GET".

+--- Root
|    +--- Folder 1
|    |    +--- Folder 2
|    |    |--- Archive 1
|    |    |    +--- Folder 4
|    |    |    |--- Archive 2
|    |    |    |--- File 2
|    |    |    \--- Folder 5
|    |    \--- Folder 3
|    \--- File 1


# Если сейчас пользователь нажмёт на
# "Archive 2", то у меня будут проблемы,
# потому что сервер обязан будет помнить
# пароль от первого архива и должен
# запросить пароль от второго архива.
# Каждый раз сервер начинает обход папок
# с корня "ROOT" как функция
# "scandir".
```

---

Мне хранить пароль на сервере? В сесcии? Заставлять пользователя вводить сразу список паролей? Хранить в js? Как хранить и передавать их безопасно?

---

Что насчёт этой задачи думает REST идеология? Это исключение или тут есть какое-то красивое решение? Если я буду хранить пароли на сервере в открытом виде, как часто мне следует очищать сессию пользователя?

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать POST вместо GET?

Comment: стандартный подход: пароль высылается через форму как обычно POST-запросом, а цепочка всех предыдущих паролей (по цепочке вложенных архивов) лежит в скрытом поле формы

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko, ни в чём. Возможно, так и следует сделать.

Comment: @ESkri, интересное решение. Я в основном использую AJAX. В таком случае я могу отправить список паролей просто в теле запроса? И храниться он (список) будет на JS до перезагрузки страницы. Так допустимо?

Comment: то, что я предложил, будет работать даже на JS-free сайтах.  А с JS вы можете пароли даже в куках хранить.

Comment: @ESkri безопасно ли хранить пароли в куках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никто не ответил, как сделать это лучше всего и безопасно (много букв в вопросе), поэтому я предложу сценарий, который скорее всего я реализую и буду ждать комментариев, чтобы отредактировать ответ.

0. Пользователь отправляет `GET` запрос, содержащий **путь** к папке.
1. Если сервер узнаёт, что требуется **пароль** от архива (или его части), которую намерен открыть пользователь, то сервер возвращает `Forbidden`.
2. В таком случае, пользователь вводит во всплывающее окно **пароль** от указанного архива. **Пароль** сохраняется в переменную в `JS`. Пользователь на `JS` генерирует **публичный** и **приватный** ключи.
3. С помощью `AJAX` `POST` запроса с `csrf` токеном, пользователь в теле запроса отправляет **приватный** ключ и случайный `id` на сервер.
4. Сервер сохраняет **приватный** ключ в сессии пользователя (и `id` пароля) на 3 часа.
5. Если запрос прошёл успешно, пользователь уничтожает **приватный** ключ в памяти `JS`
6. Пользователь снова отправляет `GET` запрос, содержащий **путь** к папке, но в этот раз в параметры запроса добавляет **пароль** от архива, зашифрованный **публичным** ключом и ранее отправленный `id` **приватного** ключа.
7. Сервер достаёт из сессии пользователя **приватный** ключ под указанным идентификатором `id` и пытается им расшифровать **пароль** от архива, а затем пытается этим паролем распаковать архив. Когда архив распакован, пользователю отправляется сгенерированное `JSON` представление папок в архиве, а **пароль** уничтожается из памяти сервера. Но **приватный** ключ остаётся в сессии до истечения срока действия (3 часа).